# Создание словаря из списка

Tags: python, массивы, list, словари

есть список:

```
['красное', 'яблоко', 'круглое', '', 'красный', 'помидор', 'круглый', '', '', 'морковь', 'длинная', '', 'зеленый', 'арбуз', 'круглый', '']
```

Каждый четвертый элемент списка - это разделитель.

Из этого списка нужно получить словарь вида:

```
{'яблоко':  'красное', 'круглое',
 'помидор': 'красный', 'круглый',
 'морковь': '', 'длинная',
 'арбуз':   'зеленый', 'круглый'}
```

Пытаюсь использовать `join`, но нужного результата достичь не могу, заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = {data[i]:(data[i-1], data[i+1]) for i in range(1, len(data), 4)}
```

---

результат:

```
In [10]: res
Out[10]:
{'яблоко': ('красное', 'круглое'),
 'помидор': ('красный', 'круглый'),
 'морковь': ('', 'длинная'),
 'арбуз': ('зеленый', 'круглый')}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
vegs = ['красное', 'яблоко', 'круглое', '', 'красный', 'помидор', 'круглый', '', '', 'морковь', 'длинная', '', 'зеленый', 'арбуз', 'круглый', '']

d = dict()

for i in range(0, len(vegs), 4):
    d[vegs[i+1]] = (vegs[i], vegs[i+2])

print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{'яблоко': ('красное', 'круглое'), 'помидор': ('красный', 'круглый'), 'морковь': ('', 'длинная'), 'арбуз': ('зеленый', 'круглый')}
```